# Trouble using cblas_dgemm for matrix multiplication in Swift

Tags: swift, matrix, matrix-multiplication, accelerate-framework

I'm new to swift and am trying to use the Accelerate framework to multiply two matrices.

However I cannot get this to work. Any help would be appreciated. Code is below:

```
import Accelerate

let firstMatrix :[[Float]] = [[1,2],[2,3]]
let secondMatrix : [[Float]] = [[3,2],[1,4]]
var answerMatrix :[[Float]] = [[0,0],[0,0]]

cblas_dgemm(CblasRowMajor, CblasNoTrans, CblasNoTrans, 2, 2, 2, 1.0, firstMatrix, 2, secondMatrix, 2, 0.0, &answerMatrix, 2)

print(answerMatrix)
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems:

- `cblas_dgemm()` is for "double precision matrices", i.e. the elements have the `Double` type. For `Float` (single-precision) matrices use  `cblas_sgemm()`.
- Each matrix must be passed to the function as a pointer to a one-dimensional array.

Example:

```
let firstMatrix :  [Double] = [1,2 , 2,3]
let secondMatrix : [Double] = [3,2 , 1,4]
var answerMatrix : [Double] = [0,0 , 0,0]

cblas_dgemm(CblasRowMajor, CblasNoTrans, CblasNoTrans, 2, 2, 2, 1.0,
    firstMatrix, 2, secondMatrix, 2, 0.0, &answerMatrix, 2)

print(answerMatrix)
// [5.0, 10.0, 9.0, 16.0]
```

Comment: To help with understanding, i tried to modify your example with 3x3 matrix dot a 3x2 matrix to get a 3x2 answer matrix let firstMatrix :  [Double] = [1,2,3 , 4,5,6, 7,8,9]
let secondMatrix : [Double] = [1,4, 2,5, 3,6]
var answerMatrix : [Double] = [0,0, 0,0, 0,0]

cblas_dgemm(CblasRowMajor, CblasNoTrans, CblasNoTrans, 3, 2, 3, 1.0,
            firstMatrix, 3, secondMatrix, 3, 0.0, &answerMatrix, 3) but i got a SIGABRT

Comment: Ok. I got whats wrong, the last few Int32 arguments are "columns" of A, B, and C. The apple documentation called them lda, ldb, and ldc, which confuse me to think they are # of rows.

Answer (score 1):

**Martin R**'s answer addresses your actual direct question.  I want to note, though, that if you're really just working with 2x2 matrices (and not arbitrarily large matrices), you may find it easier to use the `simd` module:

```
import simd

let firstMatrix = float2x2(rows: [[1,2],[2,3]])
let secondMatrix = float2x2(rows: [[3,2],[1,4]])
let answerMatrix = firstMatrix * secondMatrix
```